# System resume from suspend after 13.04 upgrade

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, suspend

My system always was able to suspend and resume properly under 12.10 and 12.04 and earlier, but immediately after the 13.04 upgrade, I find it crashes on trying to return from suspend.  Sometimes it just repaints part of the screen with a bit of the startup/splash graphic then halts, and sometimes it gets a bit further, blanking the screen and showing a mouse pointer - which is frozen.

Hardware is a AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 945 Processor × 4 on an nvidia motherboard, 8GB RAM, GeForce GTX 550 Ti/PCIe/SSE2/3DNOW!, running Ubuntu 13.04 32 bit.

Can't find anything that seems relevant in the system log - maybe I don't know what to look for though, even which log.  I will post anything requested.

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed that the system became unresponsible after waking up from suspend. I was able to log in to console (CTRL+ALT+F1) and in dmesg I got repeating messages:

```
[11534.631190] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0]  ILLEGAL_MTHD ILLEGAL_CLASS
[11534.631191] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch -1 [0x001fb24000] subc 2 class     0x0000 mthd 0x0860 data 0xffffffff
[11534.631202] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0]  ILLEGAL_MTHD ILLEGAL_CLASS
[11534.631204] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch -1 [0x001fb24000] subc 2 class   0x0000 mthd 0x0860 data 0xffffffff
[11534.631214] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0]  ILLEGAL_MTHD ILLEGAL_CLASS
[11534.631216] nouveau E[  PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] ch -1 [0x001fb24000] subc 2 class 0x0000 mthd 0x0860 data 0x00ffffff
```

Noveau is an opensource nvidia accelerated driver.

So I decied to remove `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` and reinstalled proprietary driver `nvidia-current`.

Now the system is suspendable and wakeable again.

Comment: I think this is slightly different.  My system dies completely, and I cannot get to a console.  I was already using a prop. driver, but there was a newer one available so I updated that.  No difference unfortunately, it still fails to resume.